# Interactive Chart sample from google developers showing error eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

I just import project.I get error signs at res and src folders. I decided to create a project from existing code.I still get error.I get errors not for all project but for a few projects,mainly all google samples:

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.wizards.newproject.NewProjectCreator.createProjectAsync(NewProjectCreator.java:677)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.wizards.newproject.NewProjectCreator.access$0(NewProjectCreator.java:590)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.wizards.newproject.NewProjectCreator$3.execute(NewProjectCreator.java:400)
    at org.eclipse.ui.actions.WorkspaceModifyOperation$1.run(WorkspaceModifyOperation.java:106)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2344)
    at org.eclipse.ui.actions.WorkspaceModifyOperation.run(WorkspaceModifyOperation.java:118)
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.run(ModalContext.java:121)
Caused by: org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.ResourceException: Invalid project description.
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Project.checkDescription(Project.java:175)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Project.assertCreateRequirements(Project.java:53)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Project.create(Project.java:287)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Project.create(Project.java:269)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.wizards.newproject.NewProjectCreator.createEclipseProject(NewProjectCreator.java:727)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.wizards.newproject.NewProjectCreator.createProjectAsync(NewProjectCreator.java:660)
    ... 6 more
Root exception:
org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.ResourceException: Invalid project description.
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Project.checkDescription(Project.java:175)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Project.assertCreateRequirements(Project.java:53)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Project.create(Project.java:287)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Project.create(Project.java:269)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.wizards.newproject.NewProjectCreator.createEclipseProject(NewProjectCreator.java:727)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.wizards.newproject.NewProjectCreator.createProjectAsync(NewProjectCreator.java:660)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.wizards.newproject.NewProjectCreator.access$0(NewProjectCreator.java:590)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.wizards.newproject.NewProjectCreator$3.execute(NewProjectCreator.java:400)
    at org.eclipse.ui.actions.WorkspaceModifyOperation$1.run(WorkspaceModifyOperation.java:106)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2344)
    at org.eclipse.ui.actions.WorkspaceModifyOperation.run(WorkspaceModifyOperation.java:118)
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.run(ModalContext.java:121)
Contains: OK
Contains: C:\Users\ramapriya\workspace\InteractiveChart overlaps the location of another project: 'InteractiveChart'
```

I restarted eclipse.my computer,cleared all projects.Got no clue how to solve this.

Thanks

EDIT: I need to mention that some projects run successfully with no errors(before) now show errors.The projects work just fine/

[image: project explorer]

Comment: is ur project working in previous workspace?

Comment: yes.the projects used to work.even the google sample I downloaded from dev site dont work.some projects work.i've got no clue.

Comment: make sure ur path of sdk is proper if u r using new workspace ..

Comment: I checked it.Its fine.The thing is some projects run.Others just dont.bt they used to.

Comment: ohhh +1 for ur question and may be project u r importing u may need some library or something must be missing go to property and check once java build path

Comment: could you elaborate?Sry im not familiar with eclipse or android.

Comment: enter here : http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34961/stacks28

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I tried changing the themes,the java files.Nothing worked.All I had to do was:

1. Go to project properties(Right Click your project)
2. Go to Android Target,Click most Recent.
3. Ok, Apply,there you go! :D